# PHP execution with <a> linking to other page

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a PHP page with a form, whose action is another PHP file (send.php).

When this page is loaded it sends data from the form to a MySQL table.

Now in this send.php I have 2 links. But I want to know if the user that just sent info through the form also clicks on the links.

My idea was to create a new table and execute the mysql query again, but in a new table, in order to compare who did the 2 actions (form and click on links) and who did just the form one.

First idea was to create a session after the form query, so with JavaScript I can trigger a query again after clicking on one of the links.

But the links forward to an external page (they are social media sharing links).

Any ideas how to do this?

**Update:** Now im trying with
`<a href="shared.php" onclick="window.open('https://site_to_open');">Link Text</a>`

Problem is that after first query in current page (send.php), variables doesn't keep stored. 
I also tried with:
`session_start();`
`$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];`

But variables are not stored too.

> Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in [...]

Comment: Use AJAX, once the link is triggered, use AJAX to perform the mysql thing, and then redirect as required.

Answer (score 0):

You could let the links point to a local script and append the actual external links as a parameter. In that script, just log the click or whatever you wanna do with that. Finally, redirect to the external site with the usual header('Location: ...'); stuff.

cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I solved this with the method explained on the update. My problem there was not using `session_start();` in the second page, shared.php. Now its working like a charm. So the code for those who are trying to atempt this:
In send.php:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM people");
mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO people (name,email) VALUES ('".$_POST['nombre']."', '".$_POST['email']."')");`
```

And then, in shared.php:

```
session_start();
mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM shared");
mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO shared (name,email) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['name']."', '".$_SESSION['email']."')");`
```